# Split en Java, como detectar que no exista separador

Tags: java, split

Estoy separando una palabra en Java cuyo separador es un -, mi problema viene en que a veces no tiene - para separar y por tanto me da un error, como podría detectar previamente que no existe el separador.
Un ejemplo para que se entienda:
Es decir así funciona correctamente

```
String palabra="hola-adios";
```

Pero si paso por el Split una cadena sin separador como la siguiente, hay una excepción:

```
String palabra2="hola";
```

Comment: agrega el código  que tienes por favor

Comment: `.split ("\\-");` debería retornar un array de size 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza el método `contains()` de la clase `String` que te permite saber si una cadena contiene otra dentro.

```
if (palabla.contains("-")) {
    // Aplicas el split
}
```

Comment: Gracias, era justo lo que necesitaba, no conocía este método :)

Answer (score 4):

Los String en java tienen un método llama contains, que te devuelven un valor booleano si la cadena contiene otra...

Prodias usarla de esta forma:

```
if (palabra.contains("-")) {
    String[] identificador = palabra.split("-");
    // Lo que deses hacer con eso
}
```